# how to parse results from delegate function into a string - swift

Tags: swift

I have this delegate function:

```
extension AppDelegate: SirenDelegate {


  func sirenNetworkCallDidReturnWithNewVersionInformation(lookupModel:     SirenLookupModel) {

// ^ need to convert the results into a string that can be used elsewhere 

  }


}
```

this is how im trying to do it:

```
siren.alertMessaging = SirenAlertMessaging(updateTitle: "Plese update!",
                                           updateMessage: SirenDelegate.sirenNetworkCallDidReturnWithNewVersionInformation.(lookupModel: <#T##SirenDelegate#>),
                                           updateButtonMessage: "Update Now",
                                           nextTimeButtonMessage: "Remind Me",
                                           skipVersionButtonMessage: "Skip")
```

(it's under the updateMessage: variable)

```
updateMessage: SirenDelegate.sirenNetworkCallDidReturnWithNewVersionInformation.(lookupModel: <#T##SirenDelegate#>)
```

but it gives me errors (Expected member name following '.') but there are no other names to use...

That delegate functions returns data in this way:

```
SirenLookupModel(results: [Siren.SirenLookupModel.Results(appID: 999, currentVersionReleaseDate: "2018-08-08T19:45:14Z", minimumOSVersion: "9.0", releaseNotes: Optional("This is a bug fix update"), version: "1.1.11")])
```

I am trying to display the part about "This is a bug fix update" as the message in the string.

Comment: What error does it give?

Comment: Expected member name following '.'

Comment: Add the error the the question. Copy paste it from the log.

Comment: Why do you have `.` in this line before brackets `SirenDelegate.sirenNetworkCallDidReturnWithNewVersionInformation.(lookupModel: <#T##SirenDelegate#>)`

Comment: Also show the `SirenLookupModel` class.

Answer (score 0):

Don't call delegate methods yourself. Delegate methods are called by the target class.

The delegate method returns the information you need in the `lookupModel` parameter. When it's called show your alert.

I'm not sure what `SirenLookupModel` actually contains, so `lookupModel.results[0].releaseNotes` might be wrong but it gives you an impression of the workflow.

```
func sirenNetworkCallDidReturnWithNewVersionInformation(lookupModel:  SirenLookupModel) {
    siren.alertMessaging = SirenAlertMessaging(updateTitle: "Please update!",
                                       updateMessage: lookupModel.results[0].releaseNotes,
                                       updateButtonMessage: "Update Now",
                                       nextTimeButtonMessage: "Remind Me",
                                       skipVersionButtonMessage: "Skip")

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are going about this the wrong way since you are not supposed to call the delegate func yourself, that will be done by for you, instead in the delegate method you should take care of the result in the parameter, something like

```
var updateMessage: String?

func sirenNetworkCallDidReturnWithNewVersionInformation(lookupModel: SirenLookupModel) {
    self.updateMessage = lookupModel.results[0].releaseNotes
}
```

and then use the `updateMessage` property in your alert

Comment: when I do that I get. Value of type 'AppDelegate' has no member 'updateMessage' I should put putting that code in the application code block right?

Comment: You need to add the property `updateMessage` to AppDelegate